# AngularJS app - Google Analytics Default URL?

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics

We have written an AngularJS application and want to begin tracking correctly.

In the Admin section of our GA page for this site, what would be the Default URL if our application url looks like this:

http://www.example.com/srv/Home/OLTest#/pSignIn/test%5E4599/1189608/42

The app begins at Home/OLTest, anything after the # is parameters for the app. pSignIn is our initial controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default URL field should be your hostname without the trailing slash:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042508

The default URL value used to be used for things like pre-populating your tracking code cookie domain (before using `'auto'` was supported) as well as cross-domain configuration. But I believe now it's only used for content links in your reports.

So, given your example, the default URL should be: `http://www.example.com` (without the trailing slash).

Comment: I tried using that but it returns 404 because the AngularJS app doesn't return anything for the default URL.

Comment: What returns a 404? The Google Analytics interface when you try to save that setting?

Comment: If you try to navigate to that url.

Comment: It shouldn't matter that the actual address returns a 404. GA uses that as a base to construct other URLs. Is it giving you an error while trying to save that value?

Comment: No, but it continues to show that it is an invalid value after it runs its checks

Comment: So either ignore the warning or add a route for that in your app. If it *really* bothers you, you can click the "send feedback" link in the bottom right of your screen in Google Analytics, and let the team know.

Comment: FWIW, I don't get indication of an invalid value when I do what you're describing.